# Is there a way to use input from my PS3 controller in python?

Tags: python

I'm trying to find a way to use my PS3 controller in python, and just searching around I've only found ways to do this on a Raspberry Pi or on some linux software, but I'm just using windows here.

This could either be some library made for controllers or possibly I don't mind getting the input directly from the USB somehow and programming that myself

Comment: Have you tried using `pygame`?

Comment: @MattClark I've tried using pygame but it didn't really work, I tried fixing that but all the answers were given to Raspberry Pi users

Comment: But python is python, what made the answers specific to the RPi and not applicable to you?

Comment: there seems to be some kind of installation I need to do first before it can work with Pygame

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`inputs`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/inputs) library on PyPI seems aimed at this.

Comment: @MattClark Dude, there is no minimum requirement for an answer if it solves the OP's problem. "I'm trying to accomplish X" "here's a library that lets you accomplish X" is a perfectly valid answer. If you think there is a better answer, provide one yourself.

Comment: Yeah that answer is exactly what I needed, thanks a lot.

Comment: @Amber There sort of is: ["Why and how are some answers deleted? (...) - barely more than a link to an external site"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers). If the question was "What tool can I use to do X?", then your answer would be acceptable, but we all know that this question would be off-topic. An actual good answer would be to provide an example on how to use that library. I do think your answer is helpful _now_, but we all know that external resources have the tendency to go offline.

Comment: @VincentSavard If you want to go by the letter of the rule rather than the spirit, perhaps. However there's a far cry difference between pointing to a package in the official package repository and linking to a random blog post.

Comment: I am not trying to argue that your answer is not correct, I am just arguing that it could use _more_ content. Both this question could be closed for asking for libraries, and your answer could be deleted as being strictly a link. Both question and answer are probably already in these review queues.

Comment: @MattClark which is fine, if SO wants to continue to be deletionist then it will continue to be deletionist. In the meantime, I'll go back to helping OPs, which is what I've been doing for the past 7-odd years.